# CRON job with Symfony and mailer

Tags: symfony, cron

I'm trying to set up a CRON job sending an email to users, using Symfony commands.
The emailing part works. If I type the command in the proper directory, I do receive my email.

So I came up with this CRON command :
cd /home/c1583306c/public_html && php bin/console app:send-email:send

But when the command is executed, Symfony doesnt seem to recognize my command, here is the output :

```
Symfony 5.2.3 (env: dev, debug: true)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -e, --env=ENV         The Environment name. [default: "dev"]
      --no-debug        Switches off debug mode.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                                      Displays information about the current project
  help                                       Displays help for a command
  list                                       Lists commands
 app
  app:send-email:send                 My test command
 assets
  assets:install                             Installs bundles web assets under a public directory
 cache
  cache:clear                                Clears the cache
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

NOTE: I have to specify to folder. Otherwise, this will be the output :

Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.15
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.

Comment: Please share more details - what you've given does not look like a "cron command", as `cd` is missing in the front. Also, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Yes it’s a tippo sorry. The cd is here but it’s not working

Comment: Then please share more details about your debugging attempts

Comment: I tried to run a different command (help), the result is the same. I'm trying to look for a different way to execute the command but atm I cant figure out.

Comment: Just to be sure, your cron command `cd /home/c1583306c/public_html && php bin/console app:send-email:send` does not work, right? What happens if you enter the same in your shell, e.g. when you ssh into the machine and then run `cd /home/c1583306c/public_html && php bin/console app:send-email:send`? What about using `php /home/c1583306c/public_html/bin/console app:send-email:send` instead?

Comment: If I enter it in shell, it works. I tried both of them. 
But if it's a cron job, it doesnt work. It's the same result as if I entered just php bin/console without anything after. I'm pretty sure CRON is not executing commands the same way as bash

Comment: That sounds strange - I'm also calling some Symfony commands using cron, and this works perfectly. Please share more details about your configuration - how **exactly** did you configure your crontab?

Comment: My crontab is configured with a GUI, using cPanel. It works fine with other stuff

Comment: Is the user running the cron job the same as the one you are using in the shell? It could be missing environment variables. Are you using "real" environment variables or a .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My web hoster figured out the solution, without telling me why it wasnt working.

Solution :

/usr/local/bin/php /home/c1583306c/public_html/bin/console app:mail